# Matrices orthongonality and getting values from shaders

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, hlsl, cg

My first question is that , is the `_Object2World` Matrix Orthogonal ? I mean , is the inverse transpose of `_Object2World` is equal to `_Object2World` Matrix ? :

```
_Object2World  = Inverse Transpose  (_Object2World ) //is orthogonal ?
```

Because I had test this two last lines for normal transformation and I had get same result :

```
 V2F vertexProgram(vertexInput input)
  {
   V2F output;

   float4x4 modelMatrix = _Object2World;
   float4x4 modelMatrixInverse = _World2Object; 
   float4x4 modelMatrixInverseTranspose = transpose(modelMatrixInverse);

   output.viewDir = float3(mul(modelMatrix, input.vertex) -
          float4(_WorldSpaceCameraPos, 1.0));



    //output.normalDir = mul(_Object2World,float4(input.normal,0));

    output.normalDir = mul(modelMatrixInverseTranspose,float4(input.normal,0));
  }
```

And the last question, I want to get a value from shader , so I have define a uniform property for a shader like below :

```
Properties{
 _MyCustom ("Custome",Float)=0;
}
SubShader{
 Pass{
   V2F vertexProgram(APPINPUT input){
      .
      .
      .
      //I want to debug this Condition and watch it's result.//
      if(Condition1==Condition2) _MyCustom=-1;
   }
 }
}
```

But the code below won't update the property . How can I see if the condition is satisfied?

Comment: Condition11=Condition2 is an assignment.

Comment: if I throw the condition away,  not working also

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please ask them separately. This makes it easier for people who can answer only one question and it makes the questions easier to find later on.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: It depends on the transformations that are applied to the object. If these transformations are all orthogonal (i.e. only translations, rotations, reflections, and *no scaling*), the resulting object-to-world matrix will be orthogonal, too.

To answer your second question: You can't modify properties from a shader program and read them back in your main code. If you want to use shaders for general computations, have a look at [Compute Shaders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ComputeShaders.html).